# How to authenticate and redirect to external application for SSO?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, single-sign-on

I am trying to implement a simple SSO feature in my spring-based web application. Scenario:

1. I have a main application Application1 and a secondary Application2. Both have their own login mechanisms (using spring-security login-forms) in place.
2. I want to implement SSO in Application1, so that when user logs-in to Application1, he can also seamlessly access Application2 via a link without having to fill up login details for Application2.

Here's what I have tried:

1. I created an API in Application2 which takes email as input, validates it, creates user session, and returns a url string.

   ```
   @RequestMapping(path = "/sso/login", consumes = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String login(@RequestBody SSOparams params, HttpServletRequest req, ModelMap model) {

   // 1. validates email from params

   // 2. creates Authentication object:
   UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authReq = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
   Authentication auth = authManager.authenticate(authReq);
   SecurityContext sc = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
   sc.setAuthentication(auth);
   HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
   session.setAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, sc);

   // 3. returns a url string:
   return "/user/dashboard";
   }
   ```
2. User logs-in to Application1.
3. Inside Application1's home-page, when user clicks on a Application2's link, a call is made to Application1's controller method.
4. Application1's controller method calls Application2's login API with an email parameter, and finally redirects to the url returned from the API.

   Application1's controller method:

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/callapplication2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String callapplication2(ModelMap model,HttpSession session) {
   String output = "";
   String redirectionUrl = "";
   try {
       // 1. calling application2's login API
       URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/application2/api/sso/login");
       HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
       conn.setDoOutput(true);
       conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
       conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

       String input = "{\"uniqueemail\":\"abc@gmail.com\"}";

       OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
       os.write(input.getBytes());
       os.flush();
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
       while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {  
           redirectionUrl = redirectionUrl + output;
       }
       conn.disconnect();
   } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

    // 2. returns a url
   return "redirect:http://localhost:8080/application2" + redirectionUrl ;
   }
   ```

All of the above is working fine. But when I login to Application1 and click on application2's link, I expect application should redirect to 
`http://localhost:8080/application2/user/dashboard`
without having to fill up credentials.

But instead, Application2's login page opens. I can see in the network console of Chrome that `/user/dashboard` is being called, but since the page is secured, I am redirected to application2's login page.

Does this mean that the authentication I created using API is not being used. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
        Best approach is to set filter in web.xml and put it in top of the list.

        Whenever your application will get any request it will first go to the filter and there you will check that session is present or not if its null then simply redirect to your sso login page else respective landing page.

        Now in your case,
          Solution i can see

          1) Put filter into app2 web.xml

          2) Now when you redirect from app1 to app2 (Pass one parameter anything like username, email whatever)

          3) Store it into the session.

          4) Whenever any request will come to app2 you will first verify session from filter, If username found that means user not need to login again else redirect to sso login page.

          Thats standars steps (I belive)
          5) Having a peek into your implementation.Specifically you have to add one more step into app filter. When you are redirecting from app1 for te first time with http://localhost:8080/application2/user/dashboard ( You will pass one parameter along with this url as explained above). 
          This let you to check 2 condition into your filter. Either request should have valid parameter or username should be into session. If any condition stated true you can let redirect request to further else you have to redirect to login page. 

          Hope this will help to resolve your issue.
```